# How to plot the excess returns in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code I use right now:

```
Excesstesla.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Excess.return.Tesla))+
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle("Excess Return Tesla")+
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Excess")+
  theme_bw()
```

My plot will end up like this:

[image]

my data is like this:

[image]

The script gives this warning:
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

I do not know what i'm doing wrong, can anybody give any advice?

The original data is a CSV file consisting of the two rows you see in the data in R:
[Excell file of data used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQcV5.png) Maybe there is a way of implementing the whole file right at the beginning? because otherwise I have to type 107 dates and percentages.

This is my code of retrieving the Excell file:

```
Excesstesla.df <- read.csv("excess return tesla vs Nasdaq.csv", sep = ";")
```

Comment: Your problem is that the dates in your first column are not actual dates as recognised by R.  They are simply being interpreted as non-numeric character names. The second column is not being interpreted as numbers either because it has commas and percentage signs, so R also thinks it is a character vector. You need to convert them to actual dates and actual numbers. We would need to see your actual data to help you do that. Type `dput(head(df))` into your console (but change `df` to whatever your actual data is called), then paste the result into your question.

Comment: My original data was a csv file, i just added it maybe that could give an easier solution by changing something in the implementing phase? Thanks for the answer already!

Comment: You should change the format of the second column in the Excel file, so that it doesn't have percentage signs and the decimal separator is a `.` instead of a `,` . It might also help to change the format of the date in the first column to `YYYY-mm-dd` format, but you will still have to change the column to an actual Date using `my_df$my_date_column <- as.Date(my_df$my_date_column)` . It's not unusual to have to do this sort of tidying in R after importing a csv file, and there's nothing wrong with doing it in R as opposed to Excel.

Comment: I followed the changes you mentioned for the Excell file and transformed the Date column to dates with this function: Excesstesla %<>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(Date))

Comment: This worked for me, the plot came out perfect after the changes. thanks for the help! Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 2):

as Allan Cameron pointed out in his comment the issue lies in how R interprets your data. Your Date column isnt interpreted correctly, because they are in the wrong format (see my sample data below for a format which R recognizes) + your actual percentages are also not recognized. See below for a quick fix of that in R.

Cheers

```
#creating example data which looks very close to yours, but with correct format for dates:
Excesstesla.df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('2020-06-01'),as.Date('2020-06-13'),by = 1),
                             Excess.return.Tesla = c("3,91%", "-2,03%","-0,74%","-2,43%","-0,67%","2,39%","-1,00%","2,78%","1,47%","-3,32%","5,24%","-2,59%","0,58%"))


#checking structure of the data.frame
str(Excesstesla.df) #as Allan Cameron pointed out your % values are not interpreted as numbers but as factors.

#changing Excess.return.Tesla from factor variables to numerical values by getting rid of "%" and changing "," to "."
Excesstesla.df$Excess.return.Tesla <- gsub(pattern = "%",replacement = "",Excesstesla.df$Excess.return.Tesla)
Excesstesla.df$Excess.return.Tesla <- gsub(pattern = ",",replacement = ".",Excesstesla.df$Excess.return.Tesla)
Excesstesla.df$Excess.return.Tesla <- as.numeric(Excesstesla.df$Excess.return.Tesla) # and then changing from factor to numeric

Excesstesla.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Excess.return.Tesla))+
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle("Excess Return Tesla")+
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Excess")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like what I want indeed, thank you for the backup solution! I just added my original csv file to my question. Maybe there is an easier way than typing 107 dates and percentages by implementing it right in the first time?